# Null pointer while reading data from ResultSet in Drill-JDBC 1.3

Tags: apache-drill

Null pointer at

> org.apache.drill.exec.vector.accessor.AbstractSqlAccessor.getString(AbstractSqlAccessor.java:101)

Below mentioned method is throwing null pointer becaue `getObject(rowOffset)` returns null for null values & `null.toString()` is throwing **null pointer**.

```
@Override
public String getString(int rowOffset) throws InvalidAccessException
{ return getObject(rowOffset).toString(); }
```

**EDIT**: I raised an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4128) on Drill JIRA.

Comment: OK, I am sure your question does come next ?

Comment: @Marged you are right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Null pointer exception while reading data from ResultSet in **Drill-JDBC** is resolved in Drill 1.5. Check [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4128) for more details.